# What is the 'apt-get' equvalent of 'aptitude keep-all'?

Tags: apt, aptitude

From `aptitude` man page.

```
   keep-all

       Cancels all scheduled actions on all packages; any packages whose
       sticky state indicates an installation, removal, or upgrade will
       have this sticky state cleared.
```

How to do the same using `apt-get`?

Answer (score 3):

There's none, since apt-get doesn't store "scheduled actions". `apt-get` is explicit, it doesn't do what you don't tell it to do. It doesn't remember what actions you wanted to do *before*, like aptitude does.